# Dynamically loading javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
 
Heyy guys this is my new code
```

`<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$.ajax({
    url: 'getInfo.php',
    success: function(data) {
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [{"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI",   "regex": "^http://.*"},{"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},{"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}]};


trip_progress='<div><img src="red.png" onmouseover="myclick('+myJSONObject+')"  /></div>';

var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];                                                            
var newScript = document.createElement('script');                                                                           
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';                                                                             

newScript.src = 'js/callclick.js';                                                                          

headID.appendChild(newScript);                                                                          

 document.getElementById("timepass").innerHTML=trip_progress;                                                                                                               

     }                                              
   });              
  });    


 </script>
 </head>
 <body>`

The JS code has a simple alert check out like this
http://www.vaishakhthayyil.com/trip/js/callclick.js

I am not getting why the object is being not passed in function .

Comment: eval("function somefuntion(){ alert(\"Hello\"); }")?

Comment: Can you describe better what problem you're really trying to solve?  Your code will load an external JS file called "js/calltool.js".  What problem are you having with that?  What are you trying to change? Once it is loaded, you can reference any global variables or functions in that file whether it's in an external JS file or not.  Are you waiting for it to load before trying to access it?

Comment: I don't understand, if you're going to try and load a function definition from the very same page, why not simply put it in a `<script>` tag? It doesn't seem dynamic to me.

Comment: I needed to call the function a synchronusly , actually I figured out was that I was able to alert simple string values stored in variable in main js file , but I couldn't probably alert any of the objects !

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use closures to call a function that will generate a dynamic function that you can then call, though i've never used this capability. You can find more info about closures [here](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). They are a feature of many functional programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my edit. If you [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your object, then your code will work as you expect.

```
var gmarkers = {key: 'value'};

var ss = document.createElement('script');
var scr = "function caller(){ alert("+JSON.stringify(gmarkers)+") ;}"; //alert(scr); var tt1 = document.createTextNode(scr); ss1.appendChild(tt1); var hh1 = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; hh1.appendChild(ss1); caller()
var tt = document.createTextNode(scr);
ss.appendChild(tt);
var hh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
hh.appendChild(ss);

caller();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I created a function and was able to alert 
simple String values , But I cant alert objects .What should I do !

Comment: The objects are stored globally , they are basically google maps markers , I could alert their properies like gmarker.length , but couldn't alert the object gmarker.

Comment: The dynamic script code is called after the ajax call success , I tried your code in without ajax call it works, but alert returns
undefined inside ajax success function !